# Scanner doesn't work anymore on ubuntu 18.10

Tags: drivers, scanner, canon, ubuntu-drivers, pixma

I was scanning some pages with the usual scanner, a Canon pixma mg36500, suddenly, I click on scan (after having made a dozen) and says it can not connect to the scanner. I understand immediately that it is the operating system, because if I click on the button to do the photocopy, the scanner works. So I try another PC, where just yesterday, I put Ubuntu 18.04 (the one before was 18.10) and says the same thing. So I try a Fedora live on USB and the same port, the same program there the scanner works. I use simplescan for the scans, but I also tried gimage and does the same thing. By the way, these apps are not that they have many options for scanners. Now I wonder, where should I play around for a scanner that worked regularly until recently?

Answer (score 0):

gscan2pdf downloadable from the Ubuntu Software Centre often cures problems where other scanners fail to work.

Comment: No, it also says that scanner is busy... I don't know why.

Comment: @TeodoroColuccio but, did you try it?